# Save SpreadsheetDocument in the DB

Tags: openxml-sdk

I have a valid SpreadsheetDocument object created from the stream. I can manipulate it (f.e. add new row). After my changes I need to save this changed document in SQL Server as varbinary and later read it for SQL Server to manipulate further.

Could you provide some example how to achieve it?

I know how to put/read data from SQL Server. What I'm looking for is the way somehow to convert SpreadsheetDocument  to byte array and to create back SpreadsheetDocument from byte array for SQL Server.

I'm using Open XML SDK 2.0

Thanks a lot,

Alexander

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the same but I needed to load an Excel template into memory, modify it and send it over HTTP using IIS.  I did it by loading the data into a memory stream, then doing the modifications (that seems to be the way Microsoft recomend here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee945362%28v=office.11%29.aspx

This might help you:

```
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  byte [] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("document.xslm");
  ms.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
  ms.Position = 0;

  using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(ms, true))
  {
     <Do stuff>
  }

  return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12", "output.xlsm");
```

Obviously the last line is what I needed to do, you're going to need to save the stream to the database.